# java tic tac toe winner

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

When my program prints the winner it prints "The winner is X" if O is the winner and prints "The winner is O" if X is the winner. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. I am using the turn() method to print the winner. However it is printing the next turn() letter not the current turn() letter which would be the winner. At least that is my understanding of it.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    welcome();
    initializeBoard();
    printBoard();

    while ((!checkWin()) && (!checkDraw())) {
        playerMove();
        printBoard();
        System.out.println();
        if ((!checkWin()) && (!checkDraw())) {
            computerMove();
            printBoard();
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (checkWin() == true) {
            System.out.println("The winner is " + turn());
        } else if (checkWin() && checkDraw() == true) {
            System.out.println("The winner is " + turn());
        } else if (checkDraw() == true) {
            System.out.println("Draw");
        }
    }

}

private static String[][] board = new String[3][3];

private static int row, column;

public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String currentTurn = "X";

// public static String computerTurn = "O";

public static String turn() {
    if (currentTurn == "X") {
        currentTurn = "O";
    } else {
        currentTurn = "X";
    }
    return currentTurn;
}

private static void welcome() {
    System.out.println("Tic Tac Toe");
    System.out.println("The user will play first.");
    System.out.println("Please enter your coordinates for your location row (1-3) column (1-3):");
}

public static void initializeBoard() { // initialize tic tac toe
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "-";
        }
    }
}

public static void printBoard() {

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            }
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
        }
    }
}

public static void playerMove() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Your Move: ");
    row = scan.nextInt() - 1;
    column = scan.nextInt() - 1;
    if (board[row][column] == "-") {
        board[row][column] = turn();
    } else if (board[row][column] != "-") {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please go again");
        row = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        column = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        board[row][column] = turn();
    }

}

public static void computerMove() {
    Random computerMove = new Random();
    row = computerMove.nextInt(3);
    column = computerMove.nextInt(3);
    while (board[row][column] != "-") {
        row = computerMove.nextInt(3);
        column = computerMove.nextInt(3);
    }
    board[row][column] = turn();
}

public static boolean checkWin() {
    return (checkDiagonalWin() || checkHorizontalWin() || checkVerticalWin());

}

public static boolean checkDiagonalWin() {
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[0][0] == board[2][2]) && (board[1][1] != "-")) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((board[0][2] == board[1][1]) && (board[0][2] == board[2][0]) && (board[1][1] != "-")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkHorizontalWin() {

    if ((board[0][0] == board[0][1]) && (board[0][0] == board[0][2]) && (board[0][0] != "-")) {
        return true;
    } else if ((board[1][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][0] == board[1][2]) && (board[1][0] != "-")) {
        return true;
    } else if ((board[2][0] == board[2][1]) && (board[2][0] == board[2][2]) && (board[2][0] != "-")) {
        return true;
    }
    // }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkVerticalWin() {

    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][0]) && (board[0][0] == board[2][0]) && (board[0][0] != "-")) {
        return true;
    } else if ((board[0][1] == board[1][1]) && (board[0][1] == board[2][1]) && (board[0][1] != "-")) {
        return true;
    } else if ((board[0][2] == board[1][2]) && (board[0][2] == board[2][2]) && (board[0][2] != "-")) {
        return true;
    }
    // }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkDraw() {

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == "-") {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You swap `currentTurn` when `Turn()` is called. So you are swapping the player when printing after checking if the current player has won.

Comment: Also, your second `if` branch won't ever be run because if `checkWin()` is true, it will cause the first `if` branch to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.println("The winner is " + turn());
```

to

```
System.out.println("The winner is " + currentTurn);
```

Every time you invoke `turn()` you modify the current turn.